# Возможность получения push уведомлений в desktop applications

Tags: qt5, c++, c++11, qt

Здравствуйте. Пишу небольшое приложение для чтения новых сообщений с vk на C++/Qt. Собственно, сам вопрос в заголовке. Ничего не нашел по поводу push notifications. Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли такая возможность?

Comment: То есть, Вы хотите push notification на декстопе? вроде такого нет. Да и под это нет инфраструктуры на декстопе.

Comment: То есть, единственный вариант это каждый некоторый промежуток времени отправлять запросы на сервер? Не очень удобно

Comment: Видимо придется делать так. Или использовать comet. Правда не знаю, поддерживает ли подобный функционал vk с той стороны.